# Solaris 11 and zfs, i don't understand space used

Tags: solaris, disk-usage, zfs

This is the situation.
Solaris11 virtual machine on VirtualBox as guest.
Virtual disk is 55GB
df report

```
Filesystem             Size   Used  Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/solaris-8    55G   5.9G        11G    35%    /
/devices                 0K     0K         0K     0%    /devices
/dev                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /dev
ctfs                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K         0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K         0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                    10G   1.8M        10G     1%    /system/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K         0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K         0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap2.so.1
                        17G   5.9G        11G    35%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                       0K     0K         0K     0%    /dev/fd
rpool/ROOT/solaris-8/var
                        55G   285M        11G     3%    /var
swap                    10G    12K        10G     1%    /tmp
rpool/VARSHARE          55G   2.7M        11G     1%    /var/share
rpool/export            55G    32K        11G     1%    /export
rpool/export/home       55G    12M        11G     1%    /export/home
rpool                   55G   4.6M        11G     1%    /rpool
rpool/VARSHARE/zones    55G    31K        11G     1%    /system/zones
rpool/pubblica          55G    38K        11G     1%    /var/pubblica
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg      55G    32K        11G     1%    /var/share/pkg
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg/repositories
                        55G    31K        11G     1%    /var/share/pkg/repositories
```

zpool list report

```
zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
rpool  55.5G  43.0G  12.5G  77%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

zfs list report

```
NAME                              USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                            43.3G  11.3G  4.65M  /rpool
rpool/ROOT                       31.9G  11.3G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/solaris-7             95.3M  11.3G  8.57G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-7/var         27.1M  11.3G  20.5G  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris-8             31.8G  11.3G  5.95G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-8/var         21.0G  11.3G   285M  /var
rpool/VARSHARE                   2.75M  11.3G  2.66M  /var/share
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg                 63K  11.3G    32K  /var/share/pkg
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg/repositories    31K  11.3G    31K  /var/share/pkg/repositories
rpool/VARSHARE/zones               31K  11.3G    31K  /system/zones
rpool/dump                       1.03G  11.4G  1.00G  -
rpool/export                     12.1M  11.3G    32K  /export
rpool/export/home                12.1M  11.3G  12.1M  /export/home
rpool/pubblica                   38.5K  11.3G  38.5K  /var/pubblica
rpool/swap                       10.3G  11.6G  10.0G  -
```

I have tried this command

```
for i in bin export kernel opt system usr boot home lib root var;do gdu -shc $i;done
```

give  this result

```
512     bin
512     total
13M     export
13M     total
115M    kernel
115M    total
277M    opt
277M    total
14M     system
14M     total
5.1G    usr
5.1G    total
100M    boot
100M    total
512     home
512     total
70M     lib
70M     total
1.1M    root
1.1M    total
289M    var
289M    total
```

My question is,why there are over 40GB allocated?And only 11GB free?
I reverse 10GB for swap so 55-10=40 about 6GB are used(du -shc report)
so 40-6=35GB free,why there are only 11GB free?
What i miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't (directly) delete the snapshots (moreover clones) the other replies are suggesting you to do.

Your server has multiple [boot environments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36803/be-intro.html).

You can list them with this command:

```
beadm list
```

If you do not need to rollback to a previously created boot environment, you can remove it with this command:

```
beadm destroy boot-environment-name
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed snapshots and/or clones.  Examine the output from `zfs list -t all`.

Answer (score 1):

zfs list report it

```
rpool/ROOT                       31.9G  11.3G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/solaris-7             95.3M  11.3G  8.57G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-7/var         27.1M  11.3G  20.5G  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris-8             31.8G  11.3G  5.95G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-8/var         21.0G  11.3G   285M  /var
```

as told by @andrew this is old snapshot, if you no longer need them you should delete them.

list them whith

```
zfs list -r -t snapshot
```

delete them with

```
zfs destroy -r XX
```

where XX will be result from above. I don't have a solaris at hand.

This is likely to be `zfs destroy -r rpool/ROOT/solaris-7@1970-01-01-01:00:00` (with proper date)