# Solaris 11 /var used significant space, but I cannot see it on filesystem

Tags: solaris, zfs, snapshot

I have a mirrored rpool:

```
NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                     72.1G  1.22G  39.5K  /rpool
rpool/ROOT                67.9G  1.22G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/solaris        67.9G  1.22G  19.8G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var    48.0G  1.22G  47.8G  /var
rpool/dump                1.25M  1.22G  1.02M  -
rpool/export              53.9M  1.22G    32K  /export
rpool/export/home         53.8M  1.22G    33K  /export/home
rpool/export/home/m       53.8M  1.22G  53.7M  /export/home/m
rpool/swap                4.13G  1.35G  4.00G  -
```

My /var used a lot of space, probably some logs from samba

I've read [Solaris 11 and zfs, i don't understand space used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213671/solaris-11-and-zfs-i-dont-understand-space-used) , but I haven't any snapshot for /var (I've already deleted auto-snapshots):

```
root@myhost:~# zfs list -t all
NAME                                                             USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                                                           72.1G  1.22G  39.5K  /rpool
rpool@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-27-19h04                       19K      -  39.5K  -
rpool@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-10h08                       19K      -  39.5K  -
rpool@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-11h08                         0      -  39.5K  -
rpool/ROOT                                                      67.9G  1.22G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/solaris                                              67.9G  1.22G  19.8G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris@install                                       106M      -  2.99G  -
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var                                          48.0G  1.22G  47.8G  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var@install                                   188M      -   304M  -
rpool/dump                                                      1.25M  1.22G  1.02M  -
rpool/export                                                    53.9M  1.22G    32K  /export
rpool/export/home                                               53.8M  1.22G    33K  /export/home
rpool/export/home/m                                             53.8M  1.22G  53.7M  /export/home/m
rpool/export/home/m     @zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-10h08    94K      -  53.7M  -
rpool/export/home/m     @zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-11h08    34K      -  53.7M  -
rpool/swap                                                      4.13G  1.35G  4.00G  -
```

it seems to me, the space is used by current files in /var, but when I check

```
root@myhost:/var# du -sh
  14G   .
```

I cannot find the half of my space...

UPDATE:

Okay, I've restarted samba service

```
# svcadm restart cswsamba
```

And now

```
root@myhost:/var# zfs list -t all
NAME                                                             USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                                                           39.3G  34.0G  39.5K  /rpool
rpool@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-27-19h04                       19K      -  39.5K  -
rpool@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-10h08                       19K      -  39.5K  -
rpool@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-12h08                         0      -  39.5K  -
rpool/ROOT                                                      35.1G  34.0G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/solaris                                              35.1G  34.0G  19.8G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris@install                                       106M      -  2.99G  -
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var                                          15.1G  34.0G  15.0G  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var@install                                   188M      -   304M  -
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var@zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-12h08    2.47M      -  14.8G  -
rpool/dump                                                      1.25M  34.0G  1.02M  -
rpool/export                                                    54.0M  34.0G    32K  /export
rpool/export/home                                               53.9M  34.0G    33K  /export/home
rpool/export/home/m                                             53.9M  34.0G  53.7M  /export/home/m
rpool/export/home/m     @zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-10h08    94K      -  53.7M  -
rpool/export/home/m     @zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-11h08    80K      -  53.7M  -
rpool/export/home/m     @zfs-auto-snap_hourly-2015-11-28-12h08    66K      -  53.7M  -
rpool/swap                                                      4.13G  34.2G  4.00G  -
```

What happened and how can I keep clear of this error?

Comment: I don't see any mention of multiple boot environments in the question (referring back to the [same link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213784/105132)).

Comment: I have just the original installed one, but it seems I could solve this issue...

Comment: More generally, your system could have files in `/var` which are still open, but deleted.  You could see that using [`lsof`](https://www.opencsw.org/package/lsof/) or [`fuser`](http://manutechie.blogspot.com/2013/08/fuser-and-pfiles-lsof-equivalent-in.html).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey! So is there some bug in Samba, and when I delete log files, the smbd process still hold the file, and Solaris cannot free the space in filesystem? Or that was my fault and I should remove logs in a different way?

Comment: There is no bug in Solaris, this is the expected and correct behavior. Removing log files while they are actively written by a process is the culprit. You should have truncated them instead to save disk space.

Answer (score 0):

There are many applications which keep log files open, even when they are deleted. The resolution to that differs per application by sending a signal or restarting/reloading the application. One way to claim diskspace back while a process is still using it is to overwrite it with no data like:

```
> /path/to/old_log
```

After this you can delete the file but the application will still have an open file descriptor to the file until you restart/reload the application or do whatever is necessary for that particular application to let it close its old log files.

Refer also to the `-c` switch of `logadm`

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn the compression on /var so that log files get compressed which will give some breathing room.
ie:  `zfs set compression=on rpool/ROOT/solaris/var`

In your output, I also saw a snapshot for install.  You may have old BE's also taking up space.  `beadm list`